# What does "Reputation on deleted posts and votes is not shown here" on the user reputation tab mean?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, grammar, trivial

> Reputation on deleted posts and votes is not shown here.

is at the bottom of the Reputation tab of the User page.

I know it means reputation gained or lost on deleted posts is not shown, but I don't think it makes sense the way it is currently phrased.

The following sentences are possible intended meanings:

- Reputation and votes on deleted posts are not shown here
- Reputation on deleted questions and answers is not shown here
- Reputation from votes on deleted posts is not shown here

I request the current sentence be replaced with one that makes sense. My suggestion is

> Reputation gained or lost on deleted posts is not shown

If already makes sense, please explain it.

I also believe that [pedantic](/questions/tagged/pedantic) would be most correct for this post, but it isn't available.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between those phrasings.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it should be something like

> Reputation and votes on deleted posts are not shown here

because I think that almost everyone knows what "posts" mean

I do not see reason to make "list" from it as you did

Comment: But isn't "reputation and votes" incorrect? Votes are _never_ shown on that tab, just reputation _from_ votes.

Comment: reputation from votes are shown in votes (1 line = 1 vote) http://i.imgur.com/40w9h.png

Comment: Ah, you mean it indicates that it's reputation from a vote, as opposed to other sources. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

I say ask the folks at [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) to have a look. They're crackers at sorting out sentences like that.

Comment: not necessary... I'm not from England/USA but I know what it should look like. OP just doesn't like that "posts"

Comment: @genesis I think the rather more problematic point is that "votes" is included in an awkward position, making it unclear whether "is" should be "are" (as in, reputation and votes *are* not shown) versus votes being more closely linked to the subject being reputation (as in, reputation *from* deleted votes is not shown)

Comment: yes, "votes" is in totally wrong position and I think it will/would be strange for every USA/EN ear.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the sentence is singular as the verb ("is not shown here") is for the third person singular. This means the sentence should be understood as "Reputation (on deleted posts and votes) is not shown here."

It doesn't seem the sentence means anything, except if it really means "Reputation from votes on deleted posts is not shown here."
It would also have a sense if it is referring to both the reputation gained in deleted posts, and reputation gained from votes casted from the user, but as voters don't get any reputation for voting (if by voting we don't include accepting answers), it would not make sense to make a reference to that.